# Example of a connected set where $\exists r>0$ such that $d(a,b) \geq r$, $\forall a \in A$, $\forall b \in B$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces, separation-axioms

Our definition of separation is:

> If $C$ is a subset of a metric space, then $(A, B)$ is a separation of $C$ if $C = A \cup B$, $A \neq \varnothing$, $B \neq \varnothing$, and we cannot have that $\{x_n\} \in A$, $x_n \to x$, with $x \in B$ (and also vice versa).

And the professor says that separation is not the same as if there exists $r>0$ such that $d(a,b) \geq r$, $\forall a \in A$, $\forall b \in B$. What is an example of a non-separated set (a set that fails to be separated by our definition), but meets this condition?

Comment: There is no such example. Any space meeting that condition is separated. I think you misunderstood your professor's statement. See my answer below.

Comment: In general, if you know $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$ are not equivalent, you should look for $x$ where $P$ holds and $Q$ doesn't, and should also look for $x$ where $Q$ holds and $P$ doesn't. If you find that you can do one and not the other, then you may have an implication even though you don't have an equivalence. That happens here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your professor probably means that the other condition is sufficient, but not necessary, for a space to be separated.

If that condition is satisfied, then the space is separated by the sets
$$\bigcup_{a\in A}B_{r/2}(a)
$$
and
$$\bigcup_{b\in B}B_{r/2}(b)$$

However, removing any single line from the plane leaves a separated space that does not satisfy this condition, since there are points from each of the two remaining half planes that are arbitrarily close to one another.

In other words, (condition) $\Rightarrow$ (separated), but (separated) $\nRightarrow$ (condition).